# Django authenticate: usage in login vs. register (signup): how do they differ?

Tags: python, django

I have noticed that the Django `authenticate` is used in the same way in both the login view and the register view, both return a `User` object to be used in the `login()`.

In the login view `authenticate()` uses username and password from the submitted form, then checks on `user` if the credentials are ok.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password1']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
```

The register view looks very similar to the login view. It gets the credentials from the submitted form and uses the `user` to login.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
```

Both call `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`.

Apart from saving the form in the register view, what is the difference here? Because the login (I guess) is only checking that the credentials are valid, but the register is creating a new user and, since it is creating, the credentials are new data coming in. Am I getting this correctly?

Comment: Your register form also logs in the user yes. That is not always the case for register views. In fact a lot of times one first wants to validate the email address for example.

Comment: You mean that for validating the email, I should remove the `login()` and allow the login e.g. from another view after validation.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to authenticate a user in your register method. It can be as simple as,

```
form = CreateUserForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('<urlname>')
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, '<appname>/<filename>.html', context)
```

Hence, authentication is only required while logging in as a user. And you can make your login method even simpler by doing this,

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('<urlname>')
return render(request, '<appname>/<filename>.html')
```

Hope this clarifies the situation for you :)